# Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, gradlew

[image]

why mylibrary/build.gradle is showing such error. I can not comprehend. I am using an old Flutter project and an old Gradle. My Android studio is up to date, maybe that is causing the issue. I don't know. I changed the gradle version and Java version to support my old project. The same project is working on my pc but not on my mac.

**The only error I am getting is this, any fix?**

And Why is VS code keep making this 7.4.2 in .grdale of my library. This might be causing the error, as I have nothing to do with 7.4.2 gradle. I am using 5.6.4-all. What can i do to stop making that folder.

[image]